# Openldap sync not working

Tags: server, openldap

I've installed two Ubuntu systems with OpenLdap server and made them replicate data as told in this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html). Replication worked and contextCSN had the same output + I still find original provider accounts from consumer. However, problems started once I started adding users to provider. Consumers contextCSN is not updating and I find errors in syslog on both machines.

```
Provider:
Jun 23 15:11:13 ldap01 slapd[711]: findbase failed! 32
Jun 23 15:12:14 ldap01 slapd[711]: findbase failed! 32
Jun 23 15:12:14 ldap01 slapd[711]: connection_read(52): no connection!

Consumer:
Jun 23 15:11:13 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:11:13 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:11:13 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -2 retrying
Jun 23 15:12:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:12:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:12:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -2 retrying
Jun 23 15:13:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:13:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:13:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -2 retrying
Jun 23 15:14:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:14:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:14:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -2 retrying
Jun 23 15:15:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:15:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrep2: rid=001 (32) No such object
Jun 23 15:15:14 ldap02 slapd[32562]: do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -2 retrying
```

Edit: ok, found my failure. Forgot to fix this line from provider_sync.ldif

```
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
```

Now I have no idea how to fix this if it's even possible. Probably have to return an old database backup.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the olcRootDN create a new file replace-olcrootdn.ldif

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: <admin DN>
```

After this, run the command:

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f replace-olcrootdn.ldif
```